# How to implement Abstract class in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

in App/Abstracts/ folder I have following file

1.Transformer.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Abstracts;

use eventsTransformer;


abstract class Transformer
{


public function transformCollection(array $item)
{
    return array_map([$this ,'transform'],$item->toArray());
} 

public abstract function transform($event);

}
```

2.eventsTransformer

```
<?php

namespace App\Abstracts;


 class EventTransformer extends Transformer
{


public function transform($event)
    {


                return [
                        'event'=> $event['event'],
                        'date' => $event['date'],
                        'e_code'=> $event['eventcode'],
                        'country'=> $event['country'],
                        'city'=> $event['city']
                ];

    }

}
```

Now In my Controller I am using them like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;
use App\Abstracts\eventsTransformer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Event;

class EventsapiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


     //use EventTransformer;
     protected $eventTransformer;

     public function __construct(EventTransformer $EventTransformer){

        $this->$eventTransformer = $EventTransformer; // replace 'collector' with whatever role you need.
    }


    public function index()
    {
        //
        $events =  Event::All();
        $response = array();

        return response()->json([

        'data'=>$this->eventTransformer->transform($events)

        ],200);

        //return $response['data']=$events;

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $event = Event::find($id);

        if(!$event)
        {
            return response()->json([

                'error'=> 'Event does not exist',
                'code' => 'e101'
                ],404);
        }

            return response()->json([

                'data'=>$event->toArray()

            ],200);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

I am getting following error

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 790: Class App\Http\Controllers\EventTransformer does not exist
```

Can any one help me out with this

MyQuestion is the same what How to include abstract in Laravel5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you misspelled namespace.

Instead of:

```
use App\Abstracts\eventsTransformer;
```

you should use:

```
use App\Abstracts\EventTransformer;
```

in your `EventsapiController`